# How to do Group by operation in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
form_title              eval_local_datetime    evaluatee_name   evaluator_name
EXTERNAL - pass/fail    22-08-2014 11:30:10    Yadavrao Bansod   Super User
EXTERNAL - pass/fail    22-08-2014 11:30:20    Yadavrao Bansod   Super User
Test - pass/fail        22-08-2014 11:30:30    Yadavrao Bansod   Super User
Test - pass/fail        22-08-2014 11:30:40    Yadavrao Bansod   Super User
```

What will be the output if I do Group by operation based on form title in the above records? I need to find the count of the word External if I Group by form title. I don't have SQL Server management right now. So I can't test it and I'm a beginner that's why asked here. I Goggled and didn't get clear idea that's why. Sorry if it is very basic question.

Comment: Why dont you try it out and let us know what will happen?

Comment: I don't have SQL Server management right now. So I can't test it and I'm a beginner that why asked here. I goggled and didn't get clear idea that's why. Sorry if it is very basic question :(

Comment: Well that would depend on what aggregation functions you used and calculations you might perform. What would be the length of string in my hand? So it is SQL Server is it? You should specify that too.

Comment: well the output would be the group by column [form_title] and the count (an inteer). It has 2 columns, 1 string one integer. If you are aksing us what the result would be then please go to http://sqlfiddle.com and run it there (i.e. you don't need your own SSMS)

Comment: see below, as predicted 2 columns, 1 string one integer. Is this really what you needed to know? Please re-consider your  question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
      form_title
    , count(case when form_title like '%external%' then 1 else null end)
from table1
group by
      form_title
```

will produce this result

```
|           FORM_TITLE | COLUMN_1 |
|----------------------|----------|
| EXTERNAL - pass/fail |        2 |
|     Test - pass/fail |        0 |
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03e67c/2